# prove an edge is bridge iff every chain from u to v in G includes the edge.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, connectedness

Can someone please help.  I am trying to prove the following.

Prove that an edge {u,v} in a connected graph G is a bridge if and only if every chain from u to v in G includes edge {u,v}.

in this text chain is the same as a path.  I am at the following with my proof.

--Suppose that edge {u,v} is a bridge in a connected graph G and there exists a chain that does not contain edge {u,v}.  Then since the chain must be connected by definition, but the chain is a subgraph of G \ {u,v} is a disconnected graph thus the chain contains a bridge.

Am I on the right track?  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Intuitively I understand what a bridge is, but you should provide a formal definition for a graph. Doesn't the exercise (or the book) give one?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to observe is that if $\{u,v\}$ is a bridge then there is no $uv$-path in $G\setminus uv$.

You have started your argument correctly (sentence 1). After that you should observe that $G\setminus uv$ contains the $uv$-path that doest not use $uv$. What can you conclude now?

Proving the converse should be easier.